# Where should I set a FTP user's home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, web-server

I want to create an FTP account on my Ubuntu server that amongst other things, runs as a LAN webserver.

Should I set the FTP user's home directory to `/var/www/`, or should I set it differently?

I ask because I want it to be easier to upload to this default directory instead of doing:

```
scp XXX ubuntu@ubuntu-server:/var/www/
```

every time.

Comment: But `scp/sftp/rsync` is much more secure than FTP. What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to add a FTP user via this command:

```
sudo useradd userftp -p your_password -d /home/FTP-shared -s /bin/false
```

Wherein, `userftp` is the username, `your_password` is the password, and `/home/FTP-Shared` is the path.

I personally use this in `proftpd`, but I'm pretty sure the command should be universal.

Note that this user has been created only for FTP access, and as a result does not need a valid shell (making it slightly more secure) hence the "bin/false".

So basically for your case, just create the user and set its home directory to `/var/www`. However, remember to first `chown` and `chmod` the directory appropriately so that the new user may access it (be sure to add him to the appropriate group, etc).

Comment: @MortenHagh You're most welcome. Have a good day.